# How to configure tomcat6 service

Tags: tomcat6, services

I want to change the startup parameters of tomcat6 on ubuntu, running as a service. I want to give it more memory.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, all services will grab resources as they need them… is that incorrect?

Comment: with tomcat, because it is java I need to send a command line parameter to the service. When I say service I mean it is configured to start via a script in /etc/init.d - I haven't figured out exactly where to put this parameter...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progra - that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progra) worked for you according to the comments.

I would normally include the essential parts of the answer to avoid linkrot, but since this is on another Stackexchange site that won't be an issue.